# When given N num of steps and M max possible steps return the total number possible sequences where the person can go (higher) from level 0 to level N

Tags: javascript, ruby, recursion

I feel like this is very similar to the staircase problem where you can use the fibonacci recursive call, but what's throwing me off is the second argument of M steps, I'm not sure how to apply it.  Help?

I can solve this very similarly to the staircase problem which is just a fibonacci application then transitioning using that fib helper function.

I can't seem to get it at all to work

```js
function numSteps(n, m) {
    if (n === 0) return 1

    let begin = 0
    let end = 1
    let result = 0
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        while (m < n) {
          result = begin + end
          begin = end
          end = result
        }
    }

    return result
};

console.log(numSteps(2, 6))

function steps(n, m) {
    let table = new Array(n + 1).fill(false);
    table[0] = true;
    let total = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i] === true) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                table[j] = true
                total += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Comment: Hope this is not an interview question. Please put here what you have tried so far, its better to put up a working snippet

Comment: It's a homework question

Comment: function numSteps(n, m) {
    if (n === 0) return 1

    let begin = 0
    let end = 1
    let result = 0
    for (let i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        while (m < n) {
        result = begin + end
        begin = end
        end = result
        }
    }

    return result
};

Comment: Your code is `JavaScript` but you tagged he question with `Ruby`. What language should you use for your homework?

Comment: I tagged both because either of the languages would suffice, they're just the ones i happen to know

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding of the problem: "Starting at step 0, how many ways can a person reach step n in no more than m steps, each step being 1 up or 1 down"?

Comment: From what I understand of the question, it's from a textbook, you start at 0, N is the total amount of steps from 0 to N, and M is a dynamic number that dictates the maximum amount of steps a person can take in one given step.  i.e if there are 50 steps, you start at 0 and if M is 3, you can take 3 steps at a time.

Comment: So one can only go to a "higher" step? You need to edit your question to state the problem clearly at the beginning. Having done so you could simplify the title somewhat.

Comment: I mean, Cary Swoveland, I apologize that it wasn't implied that you can't go lower, it seemed a little obvious that since you are going from level 0 to N, it would be higher.         I've also tried a method of tabulation:                    function steps(n, m) {
    let table = new Array(n + 1).fill(false);
    table[0] = true;
    let total = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
        if (table[i] === true) {
            for (let j = 1; j <= m; j++) {
                table[j] = true
                total += 1
            }
        }
    }
    return total;
}

Comment: While it may be obvious that one could not go lower than step zero (imagining an actual staircase), that does not imply that one could never go down one step. My initial interpretation is that if `n = 3` and `m = 6`, one valid sequence would be `UUDUU`, which requires 5 steps (5 <= 6), but not `UUDDUUU`, which requires 7 (7 > 6) steps. If I interpreted that way, others may as well (and others may have different interpretations). Again, I advise you to clarify your question with an edit.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are probably the best way to solve permutation and combination problems in JavaScript. You will learn a lot by tracing the evaluation step-by-step on paper or in a text editor -

```js
const waysToClimb = function* (n, m, seq = [])
{ if (n > 0)
    for (let i = 1; i <= m; i++)
      if (i > n)
        return
      else
        yield* waysToClimb (n - i, m, [ i, ...seq ])
  else
    yield seq
}

const result =
  Array.from (waysToClimb (10, 3))

console.log (JSON.stringify (result))
// [ [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ]
//   , ...
//   , [ 1, 3, 3, 3 ]
// ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive solution in Ruby.

```
def steps(max_steps, steps_remaining)
   (1..max_steps).sum do |n|
     case n <=> steps_remaining
     when -1
       steps(max_steps, steps_remaining-n)      
     when 0
       1
     else
       0
     end
   end
end
```

```
steps(2, 4)
  #=> 5    
steps(3, 10)
  #=> 274
steps(5, 15)
  #=> 13624

require 'time'
t = Time.now
puts steps(8, 25)
16_190_208
(Time.now-t).round
  #=> 22 seconds
```

In the first example the 5 possible sequences are as follows:

```
[[1,1,1,1], [1,1,2], [1,2,1], [2,1,1], [2,2]]
```